# Animate divs horizontal to vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Alright so here's the deal right now I have div's with a fixed height of 182 x 182 pixels that float left so they align horizontially. What I need to happen is once one of the these divs has been clicked I need all of them to animate from horizontal to vertical if possible. If you can point me to s simple plugin or write the code that would be awesome thanks!

Example:

```
|-------| |-------| |-------| 
|   1   | |   2   | |   3   | <-- Box 1 is clicked, boxes 2 and 3 need to 
|_______| |_______| |_______|     be animated vertically don't necessarily  
              |                   have to move in straight lines they can
|-------|     V         |         float over or on top of eachother as long as
|   2   |   <--         |         they animate from horizontal to vertical.
|_______|               |
                        |
|-------|               V
|   3   |      <----
|_______|
```

Comment: That's the thing I don't really know how to go about this in general. I've looking into this isotope plugin for JQuery (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-partial.html) but can't seem to get it quite working the way the demo does it. If you take a look at the LayoutModes you can switch between masonary/fitrows and straightDown which is basiclly what I want.

Comment: @Yoda, I don't use jQuery - so I can give you the code. But couldn't you just animate them from their current position to one in which their x and y coords had been swapped? You could do it in 2 steps to have them move as your diagram indicates, or just swap the coords for diagonal movement - this would work for item 1, not sure what the outcome should be if #2 or #3 are clicked..

Comment: @enhzflep It would be possible, I guess but I can have any number of boxes that need to get moved. Right now I'm just using a float left to get them horizontally aligned. I was just hoping there was an easier way then trying to calculate heights and widths then moving them to a specified place because someone has had to over come this problem and created a decent plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always enjoy writing scripts like this. JSFiddle is currently having quite some problems, so have codepen instead:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yIhDK

And the code for future preservation

HTML:

```
<div id="boxcontainer">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div> 
  <div class="box box3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#boxcontainer {
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 182px;
  height: 182px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $(".box1").click(function(){
    $(".box").each(function(){
      var width = $(this).outerWidth(true),
          height = $(this).outerHeight(true),
          nrTop = Math.floor($(this).position().top / height),
            nrLeft = Math.floor($(this).position().left / width),
          top = (nrLeft-nrTop)*height,
          left = (nrTop-nrLeft)*width;
      console.log(width, height, nrTop, nrLeft, top, left);
      $(this).animate({
        "top": "+="+top+"px",
        "left": "+="+left+"px"
      }, "slow");
    });
  });
});
```

The idea behind it is that it calculates for a certain box that it is box n from the left, and puts it positon n from the top. (And vice versa)

Comment: Wow this does exactly what I want! This is pretty sweet I would have to say. Thanks for your answer and the way it's done actually makes sense! I was never good with coordinates and I'm fairly new to jQuery so thanks for the leg up.

Comment: Thanks for your answers that's pretty close to what I want but testing this solution with the site I'm making sort of breaks because since it basically just moves the box to the inverse this it what happens (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qveJf) I'm sure I can fix this eventually but thanks for the head start!